# How to create another Dataframe from original one with reverse_categorical value

Tags: python, dataframe, categorical-data

I have a dataframe as shown below
[image]

I am trying to create another dataframe from the current one which should look as below

[image] The categorical labels (Population Level A and B) are added as categorical values with an additional column to represent their values. Any pointer on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

please try this:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df_A = df.loc[:,['CountryCode','CountryName','Polution Level A','Population Level A']]
df_A.columns = ['CountryCode','CountryName','Polution Level Value','Population Level Value']
df_A.loc[:,['Polution Level']] = 'Polution Level A'
df_A.loc[:,['Population Level']] = 'Population Level A'

df_B = df.loc[:,['CountryCode','CountryName','Polution Level B','Population Level B']]
df_B.columns = ['CountryCode','CountryName','Polution Level Value','Population Level Value']
df_B.loc[:,['Polution Level']] = 'Polution Level B'
df_B.loc[:,['Population Level']] = 'Population Level B'

df1 = df_A.append(df_B).sort_index()
```